# Find $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{x^{n-1}\left((n-2)x^2+(n-1)(a+b)x+nab\right)}{(x+a)^2(x+b)^2}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Prove that $$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{x^{n-1}\left((n-2)x^2+(n-1)(a+b)x+nab\right)}{(x+a)^2(x+b)^2}dx=\frac{b^{n-1}-a^{n-1}}{2(a+b)}$$

I tried replacing $x$ by $x-a-b$ but problem is getting messy and complicated,is there any other way out?

Comment: $$(n-2)x^2+(n-1)(a+b)x+nab=(n-1)(x+a)(x+b)-x^2+ab$$

Comment: What values is $n$ allowed to take here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can write it as $$ \frac{x^{n-1}\left((n-2)x^2+(n-1)(a+b)x+nab\right)}{(x+a)^2(x+b)^2} = \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{x^n}{(x+a)\cdot (x+b)}\right]$$

So
\begin{align} \int \frac{x^{n-1}\left((n-2)x^2+(n-1)(a+b)x+nab\right)}{(x+a)^2(x+b)^2}dx
& = \int \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{x^n}{(x+a)\cdot (x+b)}\right]dx \\
& = \left[\frac{x^n}{(x+a)(x+b)}\right]_{a}^{b} \\
&  = \frac{b^{n-1}-a^{n-1}}{2(a+b)}.
\end{align}